# how do i make my non-python web app behave with phusion passenger?

Tags: python, passenger

I have a GoDaddy shared server. My frontend devs were working on a prototype and my backend database engineer needed to use python to make api requests to update his tables. He insisted on root access and of course, this is not allowed on a shared server. After prodding him a lot, he finally got it to work using the "Setup Python App" in the software section in c-panel. But this caused the frontend to crash and now the frontend devs want me to disable Phusion Passenger and of course, this is also impossible on a shared server.

The finger-pointing has been going on for a week now and GoDaddy support has not been able to suggest a solution. Can anyone here help me with this?

Here is what the web page now says:

> Error ID: eed1c4ea
>
> Details: Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.
>
> Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.
>
> You can also get a detailed report to appear directly on this page, but for security reasons it is only provided if Phusion Passenger is run with environment set to development and/or with the friendly error pages option set to on."

My frontend devs are using plain JavaScript and Laravel Blade. They say the problem is related directly with the Phusion Passenger module that is used to handle HTTP requests. They also can't read the apache error log because permission denied when they try to go there.

Comment: It's hard to help with some actual details. "Caused the frontend to crash" isn't a specific error, for one. Frontend developers shouldn't need you to disable any separate component. Your backend database engineer shouldn't need any root access...

Comment: updated the question with the error message that passenger provides.

Comment: Did you do what the error message asks you to? "read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error"

Comment: As an aside, if your frontend devs are using Laravel Blade, a PHP-based templating engine, it means there's also a PHP component to this.

Comment: the front end guys can't acces the apache server log. the error message says to read the Passenger log file but I haven't a clue where to find that.

Comment: this seems like a conflict between python and php. is that right?

Comment: It's really hard to know what's happening here, in particular in terms how the GoDaddy cPanel thing has configured your server. In general, there should be no conflict between a Python application and a PHP application.